# Development HTTP server with fastcgi support

Tags: web-server, fastcgi

I'm looking for a command-line launched HTTP server (à la [thttpd](http://acme.com/software/thttpd/) -- i.e. which doesn't require system-wide configuration) but which supports generic fastcgi -- preferably which can do its own management of fastcgi servers like apache's [mod_fcgid](http://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/) can.

Does such a thing exist?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is there something wrong with just [using Apache](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/httpd.html) then, if you like that feature-set?

```
$ httpd -c $HOME/etc/httpd/httpd.conf
```

where `-c` sets the main configuration file to use. See the link above for other options. Note, unless you are root then you can't start services on priviledged ports (< 1024). Other than this, you should be able to use apache to it's fullest in this manner.

Other limitations will include (but this is not an exhaustive list):

- Inability to run as a different user unless started as root
- Inability to run fcgi processes as another user, unless that is built into the spawn script with something like sudo.

Comment: It's the configuration file I was hoping to avoid.

Comment: @tylerl: Most webservers can be run from the command line. `nginx` is another nice webserver, config file is simple, can do FCGI, infact you have to use FCGI for dynamic content, but it won't manage starting the FCGI servers for you (designed that way for security reasons). If you want to get rid of the configuration file entirely, good luck. I'm not sure such a thing exists; specifying every option on the command line would get... hairy.